# A routine that reverses a program

Tags: algorithm, theory

writing a routine which will perform the following tasks:
Tasks:

1] takes any valid program in.prog which takes input[n] array and outputs output[k] array (n=k or n!=k)

2] now this routine reverses the program and outputs out.prog another valid program

3] out.prog takes output[k] array and outputs input[n] array (n=k or n!=k)

It just hit me.is it possible to produce correct out.prog for every in.prog ?
For simple programs if i just reverse the steps or start processing from bottom to top
relative to in.prog i should get input[n] for some output[k](Are there any exceptions?)

If I know an algorithm A that produces output[k] for some input[n],is
it always possible to design another algorithm A' which will do the opposite?
I'm mostly interested in the mathematical details of the problem.
Is there a certain name for it?(So that i can search it)

Comment: So, are you asking if we know the name of this type of problem?

Comment: What do you do if  your program is not bijective? What if two inputs map to the same output? What if a certain output has no matching inputs?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Comment: This is not possible in general. Consider a "program" `output = input * input` (1-element arrays in your above concept). If `input == -1`, then `output == 1`. However, there are (at least) two different possibilities that lead to `output == 1` (`input == 1` is also a possibility) - it's not a reversible function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Just a little example: let's assume the program produces the output `{1}` for any given input. The reverse program would now have to convert `{1}` into the input.

A little bit of a expansion:
This is rather mathematical, but I hope it's understandable. Let's consider your program as a function that takes a specific input and produces a specific output. Now we have to ensure several factors to make the function reversible:

- determinism: a function must be deterministic to be reversible. E.g. consider a program with a true RNG. We can't revert the program, because of the behavior of the RNG.
- injectivity: a function must not produce the same output for two distinct inputs to be reversible. Pretty obvious: consider `f(a) = f(b) = 0`, where `a != b`. Now we want `f^-1(0)`. Which value to choose? `a` or `b`.
- surjectivity: for any `y`, there must exist `x`, such that `f(x) = y`, if `y` is an element of the codomain of `f`. Why? Consider the reverse of `f`:  `f^-1(y) = x`. This **must** be defined for any `y` in the codomain of `f`, otherwise we have undefined behavior for some `y`.

As soon as your program violates any of these rules, it's irreversible.